# PHP: How to shorten that code?

Tags: php

I know how to code a solution to my problem, I am just interested in the shortest way to code it. Thats the problem:

I am parsing a URL, the parsing can have 3 results, local, staging or production. I figure out which one it is using a regex. I do that in a function called getServer().

Now in that function I return an array which has 3 elements which are either 0 or 1. If the first is 1 and the other two are 0, it means, its a local server for example.

Now when I get that array back I still have to write an if to see which of the array elems is 1.

```
if($returnArrayFromFunction[0] == '1') {
    // do the stuff for the local server case
} 

if($returnArrayFromFunction[1] == '1') {
    // do the stuff for the staging server case
}

if($returnArrayFromFunction[2] == '1') {
    // do the stuff for the production server case
}
```

Is there some way to shorten that code?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why function `getServer()` returns array instead of only 1 value?

Comment: How about `switch('1') { case $returnArray[0]: /* */; case $returnArray[1]: /* */; ... }` ?

Comment: @u_mulder: What should that value be iyo?

Comment: @user1856596 it can be integer (0 for local, 1 for staging, 2 for production) or string ('local' or 'staging' or 'production')

Comment: @DCoder like the yoda switch statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't return an array with the index of the value `1` encoding the result. Define three constants

```
define('SERVER_LOCAL', 1);
define('SERVER_STAGING', 2);
define('SERVER_PRODUCTION', 4);
```

And return the correct constant from your code, then use a switch statement

```
switch($serverType) {
    case(SERVER_LOCAL)::
       DoStuffForLocalServer();
       break;
    case ...
```

If terseness is your goal, shorten the switch to

```
 $serverType == SERVER_LOCAL ? doLocal() : $serverType == SERVER_STAGING ? doStaging() : doProduction();
```

Is as short as it gets, but will probanly be frowned upon :-)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just return an id number in `getServer()`?

```
$serverId = getServer();

switch ($serverId) {
  case 0:  // Local
    // Code
    break;
  case 1:  // Staging
    // Code
    break;
  case 2:  // Production
    // Code
}
```

**Note:**

If you will need to use these server ids elsewhere in the code, it may be easier to keep track of which id corresponds to which server by using a naming convention with [`define()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php). This can also make your code easier to read and thus easier to debug.

```
define('SERVER_LOCAL', 0);
define('SERVER_STAGING', 1);
define('SERVER_PRODUCTION', 2);
```

Then you can replace the above switch with the following:

```
switch ($serverId) {
  case SERVER_LOCAL:
    // Code
    break;
  case SERVER_STAGING:
    // Code
    break;
  case SERVER_PRODUCTION:
    // Code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
  $case=array_search(1,$returnArrayFromFunction);
   switch($case)
   {
     0:
     break;
     // do the stuff for the local server case
     1:
     break;
     // do the stuff for the staging server case
     2:
     // do the stuff for the production server case
     break;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
foreach($returnArrayFromFunction as $key=>$return)
{
   if($return == '1')
   {
       switch($key)
       {
           case '0' : //Stuff at local
                      break;
           case '1' : //Stuff at Staging
                      break;
           case '2' : //Stuff at production
                      break;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$code = join('', $returnArrayFromFunction );
//something like '111' / '010' / '110'

switch( $code ){
  case '111':
     //all values 1
     break;
  case '001':
     //something else
     break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getServer()` function should just return one value instead of array. And then use following code:

```
$serverId = getServer();

switch ($serverId) {
  case 0:  // local server
    // Your code
    break;
  case 1:  // testing server
    // Your code
    break;
  case 2:  // live server
    // Your code
}
```